# E: Unable to locate package jasper-lib ( also happened to libpng, and jasper-dev )

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, libraries

Hello so I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and I needed to install the following to work as a libraries for the [WRF software](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/download/get_sources.html).

- **`tcsh`**
- `jasper-dev`
- `jasper-lib`
- `libpng`
- **`libpng-dev`**
- **`m4`**

the bolded ones got installed when i used `sudo apt-get install` but when I tried to use the same technique for `jasper-dev`, `jasper-lib`, and `libpng` these are the results.

```
E: Unable to locate package jasper-dev 
E: Unable to locate package jasper-lib 
E: Unable to locate package libpng
```

Is there anyways to fix this? Because I needed those libraries for the software to work. Thanks!

**Edit** I have also tried installing `libjasper-dev` from [here](https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/libjasper-dev). I was just wondering if `libjasper-dev` is the same as `jasper-dev` and `jasper-lib`.

Comment: I don't think that you can 'fix' it. You are getting these messages because there are no packages with those name. Now you tried to install `libjasper-dev`. Did it install correctly? I don't know whether the said packages are same or not but someone expert in the field should be able to answer your last question.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht So in order to get the packages I have to download it from somewhere right? and yes the libjasper-dev installed correctly, and it got the latest update, as far as I believed.

Answer (score 0):

Those three packages are not available in Ubuntu 17.10. As for `libpng`, the equivalent package in Artful is called `libpng16-16`:

```
sudo apt install libpng16-16
```

As for the other two, the only related package I could find in the 17.10 repositories is `jasper`. I'd install this and just try whether your other software runs.

The package `libjasper-dev` is also not available in Artful, so I'm not quite sure what you did there. You can always install older packages by downloading the `.deb` file (from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libjasper-dev) in this case), but that's prone to throw errors – I do not recommend this approach unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try installing the libpng16-16 and would try to see if it would get accepted in the software. For the libjasper-dev I followed the sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev and it installed successfully. I was just wondering if it was the same with jasper-dev and jasper-lib - like it have been merge into one or was it different.